# Bun how to start dev server

Tags: bun

How can I start a dev server with bun?
In webpack you can start a dev server with HMR like

```
webpack serve
```

with a custom `webpack.config.js` file somewhere in the folder.

Vite has a

```
vite
```

command, that will run the dev server via `vite.config.ts` config file somewhere.

with Bun I tried

```
bun index.ts
```

index.ts

```
const server = Bun.serve({
  port: 3000,
  fetch(req) {
    return new Response("Bun!");
  },
});

console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${server.port} ...`);
```

but that will only always print `"Bun!"`. There does not seem to be an option to set an entry point in `Bun.serve` as there is in `Bun.build`

There is a `bun run` https://bun.sh/docs/cli/run command as well but I'm not sure how to specify a port or a url or something with it.

My main goal is to have the same starting point as when I create a new project with vite and run the dev server -> open a URL to write my JS with HMR enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to build a website with Bun.js, you can actually just use Vite with Bun, and everything will work as typical (see [the guide](https://bun.sh/guides/ecosystem/vite)).

However, if you want to take full advantage of Bun's performance, you can use Hono.js (similar to Express) and some code:

```bash
bunx create-hono my-app
```

```js
import { Hono } from "hono";
import { serveStatic } from "hono/bun";

const app = new Hono();
app.use("*", serveStatic({ root: "./src/" }));

export default app;
```

```bash
bun run dev
```

With the above code, any files under `src/` will be mapped to your website (e.g., `src/about.html` will be available on `http://localhost:3000/about.html`). You can also use [JSX with Hono](https://hono.dev/getting-started/basic#return-html).

Comment: But how are you supposed to call export actual functions with the first example. I'm only able to print output to the console/browser. I'm not able to export functions /run code / add events to Dom listeners via bun run

Comment: If you follow the exact steps on [the quickstart](https://bun.sh/docs/quickstart), up to the  **Run a File** section (not including **Run a Script** and **Install a Package**), do you see the text "Bun!" at http://localhost:3000? If you do, then everything's working fine.

Comment: Yeah I can see bun but how am I supposed to include js? I did this, I see bun but there is no other js - what can I do in order to include a separate file and call my included functions. How do you proceed in order to build a library? I can only output some text there. Could you please show me an example how export a function in order to include this url somewhere else and build a library? In vite I run `vite` and include this url in some html and do whatever I want. With bun I can just print something without the ability to call functions

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I'll update the post above.

Comment: Thank you - so there is no native way to just serve js like with vite or webpack? I actually need vite or hono or something like that. However that explains it. Thank you

Comment: There are native ways to serve full websites, but they're pretty complicated, and there's not really a reason to not use a framework. Bun isn't meant to be a bundler/server engine like Vite - it's a full runtime, like Nodejs. Depending on what you want to do with it (in this case, making a web server), you can use different frameworks and libraries on top if it.